# Dynamic Knockout Template Pattern Potential Pitfalls

Tags: javascript, templates, mvvm, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm creating a widget like dashboard using require and knockout and am wondering if anyone can see any potential downside to the approach I'm using.

I have a layout with templates and one custom binding (dashboard):

NOTE: Think of the dashboard binding as just a clone of the template binding, with a helper for layout related functions when items are added/removed from the dashboardItems observable collection.

```
<!-- snip -->
    <div>
        <ul data-bind="dashboard: { templateName: 'dashboard-item', items: dashboardItems' }"></ul>
    </div>

    <script id="dashboard-item" type="text/html">
        <li>
            <div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: $data }"></div>
        </li>
    </script>

    <script id="dashboard-container" type="text/html">    
        <div class="dashboard-container">

            <!-- other ko templates common to all widgets -->    

            <!-- ko if: configMode -->
                <!-- this section is specific to each widget -->    
                <!-- ko template: configTemplateId --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: configMode -->
                <!-- this section is specific to each widget -->    
                <!-- ko template: contentTemplateId --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- other ko templates common to all widgets -->    

        </div>
    </script>
<!-- /snip -->
```

I have a component that gets loaded via require:

```
<script data-bind="attr: { id: configTemplateId }" type="text/html">
    <!-- layout/content specific to this widget/section -->
</script>

<script data-bind="attr: { id: contentTemplateId }" type="text/html">
    <!-- layout/content specific to this widget/section -->
</script>

<div data-bind="template: 'widget-container'"></div>
```

All component viewmodels inherit from a base 'class':

```
<!-- snip -->
    function componentBase(config) {

        var self = this;

        self.configTemplateId = ko.observable("config_" + config.uid);
        self.contentTemplateId = ko.observable("content_" + config.uid);

    };
<!-- /snip -->
```

This is what happens:

1. Main page loads which contains 'dashboard-container' template.
2. A component viewmodel is added to the dashboardItems observable.
3. A custom component loader uses require to load and bind to the component's view.
4. The component viewmodel's configTemplateId and contentTemplateId are bound to the id attr of the script tags in its view.
5. KO loads the 'dashboard-component' template from the component template which then finds the config and content template ids on the viewmodel and loads them inside the appropriate areas of the 'dashboard-component' template.

The reason I am doing this is because all widgets share the same base model so there are common aspects/templates that I want to keep configured in one spot (loading template, config template, etc.) that are in the 'widget-container' but removed from this post for brevity/cleanliness.

The point is that I don't want to have to remember what to include and where to sprinkle those around in every widget template and then have to make a change in every widget if something needs to be changed.

After all that the question is simple:  Can anyone see any potential issues when using the ko template bindings in this way or can anyone think of a better way to do it?  Perhaps there is a way to give the tempalte binding a reference to a placeholder and have it injected there instead?

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Well-written and thought out, but I'm afraid the post is probably off-topic for *SO*. You could check out the [CodeReview.SE] sister site. (However, be careful to check their rules and FAQ, I'm never sure when I do good by referring someone there.)

Comment: If you do repost this question on Code Review, I suggest that you do so with concrete examples instead of placeholder comments.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with your approach. It should be fine.

Comment: Ya know, I never thought about that off-topic.  Thanks for pointing that out...I'll take a look at Code Review and be sure to check the rules in the FAQ as you suggested.  @Roy-J thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of components needing access to shared central resources, such as a data api or central application state, then it does pay to do some planning ahead.

I have my own format - not so much a seeder as a proof of concept - which includes separate modules using require, multiple components on the same page, interaction between central resources and components, and also includes support for babel - ES2015 (new Javascript) and is gulped.

https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp

An example component:

```
const ko = require('knockout')
    , CentralData = require('../../service-providers/central-data')
    , CentralState = require('../../service-providers/central-state')
    , template = require('./template.html');

const viewModel = function (data) {

    //Make service providers accessible to data-bind and templates
    this.CentralData = CentralData;
    this.CentralState = CentralState;

    this.componentName = 'Component One';
    this.foo = ko.observable(`${this.componentName} Foo`);
    this.bar = ko.observableArray(this.componentName.split(' '));
    this.barValue = ko.observable("");
    this.bar.push('bar');
    this.addToBar = (stuffForBar) => {
        if(this.barValue().length >= 1) {
            this.bar.push(this.barValue());
            CentralData.pushMoreData({firstName: this.componentName,secondName:this.barValue()});
        }
    };
    this.CentralState.signIn(this.componentName);
    if (CentralData.dataWeRetrieved().length < 10) {
        var dataToPush = {firstName : this.componentName, secondName : 'Foo-Bar'};
        CentralData.pushMoreData(dataToPush);
    }
};
console.info('Component One Running');
module.exports = {
    name: 'component-one',
    viewModel: viewModel,
    template: template
};
```

And an example service provider

```
const ko = require('knockout');

const CentralState = {
    signIn : componentName => signIn(componentName),
    signedInComponents : ko.observableArray([]),
};

const signIn = (componentName) => {
    if (CentralState.signedInComponents().indexOf(componentName) < 0) {
        CentralState.signedInComponents.push(componentName);
    }
};
console.info('Central State Running');
module.exports = CentralState;
```

You can add Models to manage specific data types, and you might want to put your configurator as a central service provider.